# Ambigous answer from Oracle SDO_GEOM.RELATE

Tags: oracle, spatial

I'm having some trobule using a the SDO_GEOM.RELATE Oracle Spatial function. I'm using Oracle 11.2.0.3 and SRIM 8307.

I've e polyline and point and relating them with the following query I've some strange answer:

`select SDO_GEOM.RELATE((select georoute from t_georoute where id_georoute = 2196), 'CONTAINS', pk_spatial.get_geo_point(43856030232), 20) CONTAINS,
SDO_GEOM.RELATE((select georoute from t_georoute where id_georoute = 2196), 'COVEREDBY', pk_spatial.get_geo_point(43856030232), 20) COVEREDBY,
SDO_GEOM.RELATE((select georoute from t_georoute where id_georoute = 2196), 'COVERS', pk_spatial.get_geo_point(43856030232), 20) COVERS,
SDO_GEOM.RELATE((select georoute from t_georoute where id_georoute = 2196), 'DISJOINT', pk_spatial.get_geo_point(43856030232), 20) DISJOINT,
SDO_GEOM.RELATE((select georoute from t_georoute where id_georoute = 2196), 'EQUAL', pk_spatial.get_geo_point(43856030232), 20) EQUAL,
SDO_GEOM.RELATE((select georoute from t_georoute where id_georoute = 2196), 'INSIDE', pk_spatial.get_geo_point(43856030232), 20) INSIDE,
SDO_GEOM.RELATE((select georoute from t_georoute where id_georoute = 2196), 'ON', pk_spatial.get_geo_point(43856030232), 20) ON_,
SDO_GEOM.RELATE((select georoute from t_georoute where id_georoute = 2196), 'OVERLAPBDYDISJOINT', pk_spatial.get_geo_point(43856030232), 20) OVERLAPBDYDISJOINT,
SDO_GEOM.RELATE((select georoute from t_georoute where id_georoute = 2196), 'OVERLAPBDYINTERSECT', pk_spatial.get_geo_point(43856030232), 20) OVERLAPBDYINTERSECT,
SDO_GEOM.RELATE((select georoute from t_georoute where id_georoute = 2196), 'TOUCH', pk_spatial.get_geo_point(43856030232), 20) TOUCH,
SDO_GEOM.RELATE((select georoute from t_georoute where id_georoute = 2196), 'determine', pk_spatial.get_geo_point(43856030232), 20) what
from dual;`

"CONTAINS","COVEREDBY","COVERS","DISJOINT","EQUAL","INSIDE","ON_","OVERLAPBDYDISJOINT","OVERLAPBDYINTERSECT","TOUCH","WHAT"
"CONTAINS","FALSE","FALSE","DISJOINT","FALSE","FALSE","FALSE","FALSE","FALSE","FALSE","DISJOINT"

From the query it seems the geometries are disjoint but also the first contains the second...
Theay are disjoing actually, but if I ask for anyrelate I got true and that's wrong.

It looks like a bug, but maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance,
Samuel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the SDO_GEMOETRY had some redundant points.
After I had removed them, the RELATE function worked as expected.
The function SDO_UTIL.REMOVE_DUPLICATE_VERTICES did the trick.

Hope this could be helpfull for someone in the future.

Samuel